# Redirect if a f:viewParam is empty

Tags: jsf, redirect, error-handling, jsf-2.2, viewparams

Сan I do a redirect (or error) if a `f:viewParam` is empty?

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="accountId" value="#{accountMB.id}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

When I add `required="true"`, nothing happens. What are the options?

Comment: There is a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *When I add `required="true"`, nothing happens*

You need `<h:message(s)>` to show faces messages associated with a given (input) component. You probably already know how to do that for `<h:inputText>`. You can do exactly the same for `<f:viewParam>`.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="foo" ... required="true" />
</f:metadata>
...
<h:message for="foo" />
```

---

> *Сan I do a redirect (or error) if a `f:viewParam` is empty?*

Not directly with standard JSF validation facilities. You'd need to do the job manually in `<f:viewAction>` (you need to make sure that you don't have any validators/converters on it, otherwise it wouldn't be invoked due to a validation/conversion error; you could alternatively use `<f:event type="preRenderView">`).

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam value="#{bean.foo}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.checkFoo}" />
</f:metadata>
```

```
public String checkFoo() {
    if (foo == null || foo.isEmpty()) {
        return "some.xhtml"; // Redirect to that page.
    } else {
        return null; // Stay on current page.
    }
}
```

Sending a HTTP error can be done as below (this example sends a HTTP 400 error):

```
public void checkFoo() {
    if (foo == null || foo.isEmpty()) {
        FacesContext context = Facescontext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getExternalContext().responseSendError(400, "Foo parameter is required");
        context.responseComplete();
    }
}
```

---

If you happen to use the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you can use the [`<o:viewParamValidationFailed>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/viewParamValidationFailed) tag for the very purpose without needing additional backing bean logic.

Sending a redirect on view param validation fail:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam ... required="true">
        <o:viewParamValidationFailed sendRedirect="some.xhtml" />
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
```

Sending a HTTP 400 error on view param validation fail:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam ... required="true">
        <o:viewParamValidationFailed sendError="400" />
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter to your page ([Filtering requests](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)):

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "MyFilter")
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,  FilterChain chain)
  throws IOException, ServletException {

  if (request.getParameterMap().get("accountId") == null){
     // do redirect
     return;
    }
   chain.doFilter(request, response); 
  }

}
```

And rememeber to declare your filter in web.xml file:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>my.filter.classpath.MyFilterclass</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/url/to/my/page.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also, when working with filters, I suggest to use forward than redirect.